# mariaDB plugin 0 is not loaded

Tags: mysql, debian

I have installed mariaDB 10.2 on Debian jessie . everything was working fine until i updated the plugin column for the root user and i have set it to `plugin=0` instead of  `plugin=''`  to allow acces to non sudo users as i have been always doing. so unconsciously i have set 0 .

Now i am not able to access to the database and still getting the same error `ERROR 1524 (HY000): Plugin '0' is not loaded`

How can i solve this problem ? can i reload mariaDB to its default status ?

Is there a way to change the plugin value from the tables files or something like that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since nobody has replayed i had to do it my self so I solved this issue by deleting (purging) mariaDB server completely and reinstall it again and this solved the problem . i believe there is other solutions but this was the fastest for me !!

```
sudo apt-get purge mariadb-server mariadb-client 
sudo apt-get autoremove mariadb-server mariadb-client

// remove all leftover files
sudo apt-get purge mariadb-*
```

and reinstalled it again :)